# Repeat a column list in Excel until end of sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I feel like this is extremely simple, but for some reason, this is not an easy thing to do in Excel. Basically I have a vertical set of values running down a column ranging from 1 to 3, but they are random. However this same sequence will repeat every 60 rows. I need the sequence to just repeat itself every 60 rows, as the data file I'm working on is tens of thousands of rows and I don't feel like copying and pasting that many times. The values run from M2:M61.

Is there a simple VBA code to loop this column?

Alternatively, is there an equation that can do this? I tried using Index, but don't think I was specifying the row or columns correctly 
`=INDEX($M$122:$M$181,ROUNDUP(ROWS(I$122:I132)/60,0),13)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted some code to do it, maybe this will give you some ideas.  It assumes that your first lot of 60 values have been entered in A1:A60 and reads them into an array, and then loops up to the number of loops (I used 12000) copying the values in by steps of 60.

```
Sub Repeat60Rows()
Dim ListArray As Variant
Dim Loopcounter As Long
Dim MyRange As String

ListArray = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A60").Value
For Loopcounter = 1 To 12000 Step 60
    MyRange = "A" & Loopcounter & ":A" & Loopcounter + 59
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(MyRange) = ListArray
Next Loopcounter
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd really like to get this working, but for some reason it keeps pasting the numbers starting one spot up. I'd like to copy the array from M2:M61 and paste those 60 numbers until M9961. Here's what I did with your code:
`Sub Repeat60Rows()
Dim ListArray As Variant
Dim Loopcounter As Long
Dim MyRange As String

ListArray = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("M2:M61").Value
For Loopcounter = 1 To 300 Step 60
    MyRange = "M2" & Loopcounter & ":M" & Loopcounter + 59
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range(MyRange) = ListArray
Next Loopcounter
End Sub`
Did I mess something up? I've played with it for a while now

Comment: Hi, a couple of things. Firstly, the loopcounter doesnt have to start at 1, it can start at whatever number you desire, and because it is being used to create your range, and you want to start at row 2, would suggest you do loopcounter = 2 to 9961.  The second thing is, inside your loop you have set range = "M2" & Loopcounter, it should only be "M" & loopcounter

Comment: Hm, I made the changes but changing Loopcounter to 2 to 9961 didn't paste anything, it just pasted over a number on the 60 I wanted to paste. I changed it back to 2 to 61 and I'm getting the same problem I had before-- it pastes the correct 60 downward, but each time it pastes in the loop, it pastes it one cell lower (n+1) than it did the last  time, leading to a bunch of repeats that I want, but they're all shifted downward, each one more than the last. Is there something in this code that may be making it jump a cell each time it pastes? The + 59 maybe?

Comment: I cant replicate your problem.  Using the new parameters you gave me, I made then changes I mentioned in my previous comments and it works fine.  I put a header row at M1 and then entered numbers 1 - 60 down to row M61.  Run my code and it works fine.  It isn't jumping a cell each time, its jumping 60 cells at a time and its using the loop counter and the + 59 to define the range each loop.  Are you sure you followed my changes correctly?  Please see updated code below based on your new parameters

Comment: `Sub Repeat60Rows()
Dim ListArray As Variant
Dim Loopcounter As Long
Dim MyRange As String

ListArray = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("M2:M61").Value
For Loopcounter = 2 To 9961 Step 60
    MyRange = "M" & Loopcounter & ":M" & Loopcounter + 59
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range(MyRange) = ListArray
Next Loopcounter
End Sub`

Comment: I'm an idiot. I thought you meant Loopcounter = 2 to any# Step 9961 in your previous comment. I changed it to what you have and got the correct repeat. I still don't know why it wouldn't paste correctly when I had it at 2 to 12000 Step 60. I probably messed something up. I may have put 61, confusing it for my range (M2:M61). Well at least I know a bit more about the parameters for loops for further projects. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: No problem.  1 final observation - The "Step" option in a loop is not somethign I personally use regularly but can be useful in situations like this.  If its not obvious, the "to" value in this solution needs to be a multiple of your step size i.e. 60 in this case.  If it isn't, all that will happen is that the very last loop will truncate and give you less than your expected loop values

Answer (score 1):

I learned a little more and realized, because this is a repeating set of 60 numbers, I could just use a simple `=OFFSET(M62, -60, 0)` formula and I could just paste down. I'm sure there's probably an easier way to automate this with VBA, but I'm unsure as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In M182

```
=OFFSET(M$121,MOD(ROW()-2,60)+1,0)
```

and fill down

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my problem well enough, but this did not work for me. When I pasted down, I simply got 0's. Not quite sure. But I followed your lead in using `=OFFSET` and I found an easy way to solve my problem. So thank you, in part.